# Angular $watch function not working as intended

Tags: angularjs, watch

So I have the following watcher on a scope in the link function of a directive. I have used this pattern for another variable and it works however this one does not. Does anyone have any suggestions. Code is as follows

```
    $scope.$watch('QOLFactory.surveysInView', function(newValue, oldValue, scope){
        console.log(QOLFactory.surveysInView);
        console.log(newValue, oldValue);
        scope.surveys = newValue;
        scope.surveyData = generateSurveyTotals(newValue);
});
```

The first console log prints the corrent value of QOLFactory.surveysInView, but the second console.log prints undefined, undefined. Is there something that I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you please give us a fiddler?

Comment: My guess is that you are injecting `QOLFactory` into the directive, but you are not putting it on the scope? Try: `$scope.QOLFactory = QOLFactory;` Just a guess, show more code. Why does everyone have to have a freaking fiddle or plunkr!? :(

Comment: If surveysInView is a complex object, you may need to add a third `true` argument to `$watch` so that it does a deep inspection. See docs here (search for `objectEquality`) : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope

Comment: Thank you @SunilD. you're answer was correct, I have to assign the QOLFactory to the $scope in the controller in order for the directive to function properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order for the watcher on directive to have access to the Service that was being injected in the controller, the Service has to be assigned to $scope variable. This makes the watcher behave as expected, and returns the correct values.